# Gcloud target URL changed unexpectedly when I wanted to deploy an update

Tags: gcloud

Usually my target url is alway `myprojectid.appspot.com` but just about some minutes ago I needed to push an update but i'm getting another target url of `myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com`
Please see the image below because I had to abort the process.
[image: b]
How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour, as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#requests_and_domains). You can also see the changes made in the [releases notes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/release-notes#February_11_2020) for Google App Engine where it explains that App Engine is now changing the URLs that you use to send requests to your apps.

As stated in the release notes:

> For example, an app can receive requests at https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com. This new URL is optional for existing apps, and will soon be required for all new apps.

If you are trying to deploy a new Google App Engine application, the URL will be the one you are seeing here https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com.

I hope it helps.